# What do you call a desperate attempt unlikely to succeed?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call a desperate attempt unlikely to succeed? For example, when other ideas have failed and you have one final go before giving up

Answer (score 49, accepted):

We might call it a **last-ditch** attempt.

Some other similar phrases, that are not exact matches, include:

- a **final** attempt
- the **final throw**
- **going all-in**

If it's almost certain to fail, we could apply the adjective **futile**.

Comment: (+1) for *last-ditch*. IMHO it fits the OP's bill completely. It expresses: "last attempt", "desperation" and "low probability of success". The other three aren't so spot-on, especially expressing "low probability of success".

Comment: Going all-in doesn't imply unlikely to succeed.  It can have connotations of committing one's full attention and resources to an effort because it's important or catches your attention, depending on how it's used.  And even when it used to mean a final effort (as in the original poker meaning), it doesn't imply it's a low-percentage bet without other context.  Closer in meaning to "bet the farm", which one normally wouldn't do on a low-percentage bet.  As Lorenzo says, only *last-ditch effort/attempt* fits perfectly.

Comment: I like last-ditch since it implies a different method, saved for last; whereas the long pass used in a Hail Mary isn't mechanically different from any other long pass.

Comment: These all express finality more than desperation.

Comment: "Final throw" or "final throe"?

Comment: @OwenReynolds there are long passes, and there are "Hail Mary" passes. A regular long pass is planned out and part of a standard play. A Hail Mary is basically the quarterback launching the ball as far as he can throw and hoping a receiver gets there in time to catch it. They are unlikely to succeed and at high risk for interception, so are strategically a bad idea unless it's the last play of the game and you are going to lose anyway.

Comment: "Last ditch" and the others here don't really confer the meaning of "unlikely to succeed". e.g., the ship is sinking, man the pumps, patch the holes, and as a last ditch effort we will beach the ship. Beaching the ship is not unlikely to succeed -- it'll definitely work -- but it's a last ditch because it has negative side effects and we'd prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 48):

Such things are often called a "Hail Mary".

Comment: Yes, I think that's the best idiom, at least in AmE. (I'm not sure about how widely it's used.) A "long shot" might also work.

Comment: As a (reasonably well-read) Brit, I wouldn't understand this term. (Unless it had sufficient context; but then you could substitute _anything_ there if it had sufficient context…)

Comment: @gidds I believe the phrase comes out of American football: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass

Comment: The phrase even lent itself to a book recently: [Project Hail Mary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Hail_Mary) by Andy Weir

Comment: @gidds "Hail mary" is a common term in American football. I would expect most Americans to know it.

Comment: I'm used to non-US English. I'd heard the expression but never knew what it meant...

Comment: Literally, it means you're praying to the mother of god for it to work.

Comment: While the phrase was popularized by American football, it probably pre-dates that usage, given the obvious religious connection.

Comment: The context is, in American football, when you have only time for one last play and you are far from the goal, you throw a very long pass and pray that one of your receivers catches it.

Comment: "Hail Mary" or "long shot" seem most fitting. A lot of other answers -- such as "last ditch" -- are really for ideas that are desperate in some way but not necessarily unlikely to succeed. e.g., the ship is sinking, as a last ditch effort, we will beach it. Beaching it will definitely stop it from sinking but it is otherwise a terrible idea we would prefer not to do. The "Hail Mary" (or "long shot") is unlikely to succeed but is the only option left.

Answer (score 14):

[Forlorn hope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forlorn_hope) - a victorian British army expression for a group of men who would storm a breach in a wall. Any one who survived would get promoted or a reduction in punishment. As the name suggests it was very unlikely to succeed.

Comment: A forlorn hope was very likely to succeed, but any given man was very unlikely to survive.  The purpose of the "forlorn hope" was to provide an opening for the follow-on troops, who would experience casualty rates typical for an open-field battle.

Answer (score 9):

I think that a good way to say this is "a shot in the dark." It's defined [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/shot--in--the--dark) as "an attempt that has little chance for success."

It's idiomatic. It refers to firing a gun (or shooting an arrow) when you can't see the target. I think it contains the desperation and unlikelihood that you want.

Comment: I wouldn't understand a shot in the dark to necessarily be desperate. For example, if someone asked me a trivia question I knew nothing about, even my first guess might be a shot in the dark even though there was no desperation.

Answer (score 7):

Such things are often called "a last gasp".

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/last-gasp

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/last-gasp

Comment: In the medical domain, "gasp" is the name for a failed attempt to breathe; a pretty impressive display where the chest of an unconscious, non-breathing patient suddenly heaves violently without any intake of air.

Answer (score 7):

"long shot" would also work

Answer (score 5):

Grasping at straws ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grasping-at-straws))

Answer (score 1):

Throwing kitchen Sink would fit your requirements. Last ditch effort is also used in the context, you have provided; but that does imply that the effort is likely to fail.

Comment: The usual phrase is 'everything but the kitchen sink' not 'the kitchen sink'.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=everything+but+the+kitchen+sink%2Cthrowing+the+kitchen+sink&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceverything%20but%20the%20kitchen%20sink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrowing%20the%20kitchen%20sink%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's not included in the Lexico dictionary: https://www.lexico.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=en_dictionary&dictionary=en&query=throw+the+kitchen+sink

Comment: Is it a joke which has apparently become a colloquialism? Throwing everything but the kitchen sink means trying everything, so if you were to then throw the kitchen sink,  that would imply that everything reasonable/likely had already been tried. The surprise (critical for a good joke), of course, is that the speaker omitted the 'everything but' from the cliche/adage.

Comment: Good answer, the web confirms the colloquial usage fits the requested attitude: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=Throwing%20kitchen%20Sink

Answer (score 1):

In the game of Chess, when a piece is threatened and cannot be saved, it can often still be used to capture one last opponent piece or pawn of lesser value before it's taken.

Normally, you wouldn't want to exchange one of your pieces against a piece of lesser value; but since the piece cannot be saved anyway, that capture is its final throe.

Such a move is called a ***desperado***.

By analogy, any last attempt before giving up could be called a desperado.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster defines desperado](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desperado) to mean only the way I've heard it used before; `a bold or violent criminal, especially: a bandit of the western U.S. in the 19th century`

Comment: @Chuck You're right. And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desperado_(chess)) defines "desperado" to be the chess piece itself, not the final action of that piece. However, the way I explained it in this answer is how the term used at my local chess club, and searching for "desperado" on https://chess.stackexchange.com also seem to give result that agree with me.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

> A last (or final) [roll of the dice](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+roll+of+the+dice)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express annoyance at a person trying some action, you might describe it as a "flailing attempt". By contrast, a "Hail Mary" is a valiant action that's unlikely to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

A million to one chance, or a one in a million chance, while not single words are common phrases used to describe making an attempt against desperate odds. In fiction of course such plans always work. It is such a well known plot device that it was parodied in Terry Pratchett in [several books](https://wiki.lspace.org/Million-to-one_chance).

[Mort](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/95458-scientists-have-calculated-that-the-chances-of-something-so-patently)

> Scientists have calculated that the chances of something so patently absurd actually existing are millions to one.
> But magicians have calculated that million-to-one chances crop up nine times out of ten.

[Guards Guards](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/794532-i-mean-it-s-a-good-job-we-ve-got-a-last)

> I mean, it's a good job we've got a last desperate million-to-one chance to rely on, or we'd really be in trouble!

Answer (score -2):

One could also call it a quixotic attempt.

- "Quixotic" does mean unlikely to succeed.
- It doesn't imply a last attempt, your first attempt can be quixotic.
- It additionally means idealistic.

You can use it to describe an attempt to do something e.g. "They made a quixotic lunge for the fleeing cat.". Or it can equally describe a person e.g. "The quixotic scholar was hard at work and learning nothing."

Comment: "Quixotic" means "impractical because it's too idealistic", not "impractical because you're all out of better options".